# standard sql error message to console too vague

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Is there a way to make console display of exception messages a little bit more precise in a c# winforms app. As in, instead of just;

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
```

Perhaps more like java's,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection at
oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112) at
...
```

At least so I have an idea about what may be wrong. I'm sure there is something for this situation but got no idea:)

Comment: Note that a "first chance exception" isn't quite the same thing as seeing an actual exception; are you seeing that in the IDE? or in the `catch` block?

Comment: in the output window of the IDE

Comment: the output window (esp re first-chance exception) of the IDE is not the same thing as the console output; you can pretty much ignore that - that *is not real*; that is a "heads-up" on stuff that may or may not bubble up later (vs being handled). The reason it doesn't show much is that (because it isn't real) it can't risk doing anything that might change state, which includes accessing ***any*** member (including `.Message` etc; properties are methods). The only thing it can show safely is the *type* information. You are comparing apples and house-bricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That extra information is basically `.StackTrace`. How precise it *can* be depends on how it was built, whether the pdb is available, etc.

If you just do something like:

```
catch(Exception ex) {
    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

you should see a similar level of information by default. Basically, the `ToString()` shows more than just the `.Message`. For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    try {Throw();}
    catch(Exception ex) {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
public static void Throw()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("oops");
}
```

displays:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: oops
   at X.Throw() in c:\Users\Marc\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleAp
plication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 30
   at X.Main() in c:\Users\Marc\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApp
lication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 20
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLException already contains enough information

Please have a look at the MSDN page
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx)

```
 try
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
            {
                errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                    "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                    "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                    "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                    "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure it is:

```
try
{
  /// your code goes here ...
}
catch(SqlException sex)
{
 foreach(SqlError error in sex)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1} Error {2} State {3}: \"{4}\" at {5}@{6}", 
     error.Server, error.Source,
     error.Number, error.State,
     error.Message,
     error.Procedure, error.LineNumber);
 }
}
```

You got it? `try` ... `catch` !

For the (few) cases where is valid to not have a try/catch block you can resort to the global handlers: [`Application.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception) for UI message pump threads and [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) for non-UI threads.